# Why does my forge bucket not show any objects?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have followed [this](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/app-managed-bucket/) tutorial and have uploaded my file successfully to: `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/timmyisabucket/objects/audobon_arch.rvt`

It has uploaded successfully and I can verify this by calling `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6dGltbXlpc2FidWNrZXQvYXVkb2Jvbl9hcmNoLnJ2dA==/metadata/c63a6682-a73c-a2a8-a08c-dfeee25781f4/properties` which successfully returns all the object properties.

However, when I ask the api to list all the objects inside the bucket, it simply returns an empty list!

The endpoint I'm calling: `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/timmyisabucket/objects`

The response:

```
{
   "items": []
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: quick question: when you checked objects inside the bucket, did you check in the same day of checking object properties? or the other day. The top on my head is you might probably created a bucket with 'transient' policy. That means, the objects inside it will be removed after 24 hours.

Comment: Ah yes it was created with transient! A quick google doesn't show anything saying that that's the expected behaviour of the transient bucket type, do you know where I might find some documentation around that?

Comment: The API help talks about this: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/overview/retention-policy/ Probably it is bit tricky to search out by appropriate keywords. sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this off, the helpful comment by Xiaodong Liang led me to the the fact that my bucket type was created with the incorrect type of "Transient" meaning that all my stuff gets deleted after 24 hours.

It should have been Temporary or Persistent.

[Retention policy](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/retention-policy/)

> #### Transient
>
> Think of this type of storage as a cache. Use it for
> ephemeral results. For example, you might use this for objects that
> are part of producing other persistent artifacts, but otherwise are
> not required to be available later.
>
> Objects older than 24 hours are removed automatically. Each upload of
> an object is considered unique, so, for example, if the same rendering
> is uploaded multiple times, each of them will have its own retention
> period of 24 hours.
>
> #### Temporary
>
> This type of storage is suitable for artifacts produced for
> user-uploaded content where after some period of activity, the user
> may rarely access the artifacts.
>
> When an object has reached 30 days of age, it is deleted.
>
> #### Persistent
>
> Persistent storage is intended for user data. When a file
> is uploaded, the owner should expect this item to be available for as
> long as the owner account is active, or until he or she deletes the
> item.